# Limit of a sequence and dependencies

Tags: limits, proof-verification

Suppose that we know that there is a sequence $y_n$ such that for each $N$

$$ y_N>\frac{4^N}{3^M} \quad \text{,}$$
 where **$M$ depends on $N$** and $M\ge N+1$. It is tempting to say that if $N\to \infty$, then $M \to \infty$ and since the function $4^x$ tends to infinity much faster than $3^x$, then $y_N \to \infty$.

However, I feel that this is just wishful thinking and very sketchy. Do you think it would at least be possible to show that $y_N \not \to 0$?

Could anyone point out either a mistake in the reasoning or give a hint on how to make the argument more rigorous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but if $M = 2N$, the condition becomes $y_N > (4/9)^N$, so the sequence where $y_n = (1/2)^n$ satisfies the condition and $y_n \rightarrow 0$.  Did you mean $M \leq N+1$?

Comment: I did mean what I wrote in the question, that $M \ge N+1$, otherwise it would have been straightforward. This problem came up in the middle of something else I was trying to solve and the sort of situation in your answer wouldn't happen (fortunately I was able to show that through other methods). But the example you gave is certainly worth keeping in mind! Thanks!